# WPF - *.exe embed in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, embed

I'm learning WPF/C# by developing a litte application.

Actually, i'm trying to embed an exe, in my case a cmd, inside a specific canvas in my main windows.

I've found a lot of examples for WinForm but nothing for WPF.

I've search inside this forum, and others, but the only thing i find is for embed an application inside the main windows without control of position and style (using FindWindow and SetParent).

Is this even possible ?

If this is possible could you explain me how it works ? Code is good but comprehension is better ;)

Comment: you mean something like ole?

Comment: I think. I found some answers speaking about OLE but it seems really old and more adapted to WinForm. I am misunderstanding something ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're trying to achieve. Do you want the consol application to run inside your window, so the output from it is directed to the form? If so, do you need to interract with it, or just run it and view the results? It's possible to redirect the output stream to a component on a form if all you need to do it view the output.

Comment: My idea was to execute a cmd inside a Canvas or an other panel object. The purpose was to have an application with a cmd integrated in it for launch a random ipconfig on it (for example). I searched during this day and i think that is unfortunately not possible.